# Where is my VHD being used in Azure VM?

Tags: virtual-machines, storage, azure, vhd

I am running a VM using Azure and the VM uses a default OS Disk (30 GB), mounted on `/dev/sda1`. I can also see another `/dev/sdb1` which I came to know is a temp disk (130 GB) auto-provided by VM.

The first OS disk is mapped to one VHD resource "Storage account (classic)" which I could see on the Azure dashboard.

However, there is another similar VHD resource also available in the dashboard and I am not sure what this is used for. Its size also is not shown so I am not sure whether that is the temp disk (`/dev/sdb`) or something else. I believe I am being charged for this resource as well but the developer who has configured all this has left and I need to fix this.

How can I check if this resource is used for actual storage or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> “The first OS disk is mapped to one VHD resource "Storage account
>   (classic)" which I could see on the Azure dashboard.”

It seems that your VM deploy in the ASM module. The temp disk we can’t find it in our storage account, and the price of disk included in the virtual machine’s price.

> “How can I check if this resource is used for actual storage or not?”

we can use PowerShell to list all the disks, we will find which disk used for which OS, here is the example:
[image]